# share plist file with today widget

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I have an app working to which I want to add a today widget. The today widget must use the app's data, which is stored in a plist.

I use the following code to access the plist:

```
let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
path = rootPath.stringByAppendingString("/Scales.plist")
```

I have created an app group called "group.com.PaulDobbs.PrescriptionTracker". How do I change the above code to put the plist file there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share files across multiple apps you ave to setup a group. You said you already did that. Then you should be able to get the URL of the shared directory using:

```
let url = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.PaulDobbs.PrescriptionTracker")
```

You must place at this URL all the files for which you need shared access, and they should be available across all apps from the group.